# Is libpq++ or libpqxx the official c++ postgres interface?

Tags: c++, postgresql, interface

I'm confused between these two. I see libpq++ mentioned for version 7 of posgresql; I see libpqxx describe itself as the official c++ postgresql interface but not mentioned in the docs for postgres 9.3, only the C interface (libpq) is mentioned in the postgresql docs for 9.3. I also see libpqxx hasn't been committed to for 5 months, and I don't seem able to be able to find a site for libpq++.

Which is the official interface for c++?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

It seems to me that there isn't an official interface for c++, they just provide libpq as the c base and hope for the community to implement it for c++(hence libpqxx and libpq++)

For more info you could check http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/libpq.html

Comment: Exactly right. The official C++ interface for PostgreSQL is `libpq`, a pure C library that's usable from C++. The others are 3rd party tools that attempt to wrap `libpq` with more C++-like patterns. `libpqxx`'s maintenance isn't exactly intensive; AFAIK, libpq++ is just plain dead.

Comment: Oh boy! Looks like using postgresql will be more fun than I thought! Thanks

Comment: LATE update: [libpqxx](https://pqxx.org/development/libpqxx/) now at least *claims* to be the official C++ client, and as of writing this comment they released a new version (7.9.0) only a view weeks ago with hints to upcoming version 8.0 (requiring C++ 20).

Answer (score 4):

Just to put my two cents. There is a statement by the author of libpqxx library [Jeroen T. Vermeulen](http://pqxx.org/development/libpqxx/wiki/WhoMadeThis):

> The first version of libpqxx was written in 2001, and it was adopted
>   as the official replacement for the older libpq++ a few years later.

So for now libpqxx is really best option to use c++ with PostgreSQL.

Comment: `libpqxx`, whatever it might claim, is NOT the official PosgreSQL C++ client.

Comment: @rustyx Excuse me for my late comment, but in that case the tag description of [tag:libpqxx] in Stack Overflow seems misleading/incorrect: it does state that `libpqxx` is the **official** C++ client API for PostgreSQL. And, judging by [revision history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/5314173/revisions), this wording has been there since March 2011. I'm just trying to find the official C++ library for PostgreSQL, and this is confusing.

Comment: @heapunderrun there just isn't an official PQ C++ client (in the sense of being "adopted" or otherwise endorsed by the PostgreSQL core team). I remember making my own by simply wrapping some PQ C APIs in C++ so that I can have RAII, after being dissatisfied with all existing [PQ C++ clients](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Client_Libraries#C.2B.2B).

Answer (score 3):

I just wrote up the story from my perspective, in the [libpqxx FAQ](http://pqxx.org/development/libpqxx/faq/).

There are alternatives to libpqxx, but forget about libpq++.  At the turn of the century it *really* needed replacing.  If I remember correctly after more than 20 years, it did weird things like "`transaction` is a subclass of `connection`" and "`transaction` destructor implicitly commits, even when you're exiting with an exception."  I wrote libpqxx because I could practically *hear* the problem say "I want to be solved differently!"  :-D

Answer (score 0):

Convert to or select [PQXX](http://pqxx.org/development/libpqxx/) (libpqxx, a/k/a "The C++ connector for PostgreSQL"). It is some work, but this is well maintained and is the replacement for the functionality (though not syntax) of libpq++. PQXX is maintained by Jeroen T. Vermeulen (principle developer, as mentioned above discussion of libpq++ of long ago), and a host of others who keep as a well developed and tested library. Furthermore kept up with latest C++ and Postgres standards/versions, and a large number of operating systems and compilers. And it's as "official" as you are going to get, when using C++. I have personally used in several Micorsoft compilers, while others using Linux etc., and I assure is as well developed and community tested as any open source software I have seen. I have no idea why Jeroen didn't just say that in his previous post here! (But he is very modest. And you'll get the best support of any software in the industry from community help on Github--better than Postgres itself, IMO! And I certainly disagree with an above comment about lower maintenance for libpqxx.)

Oh, see [Is libpqxx really "official"?](http://pqxx.org/development/libpqxx/faq/) in the FAQ. ".... So this was where the team decided that new language drivers should live in their own repositories, outside the main PostgreSQL tree." Runs on "anything that bears any resemblance to Unix (the various flavours of GNU/Linux and of BSD, Apple's macOS, Solaris, AIX, HP/UX, Irix etc.)" as well as Windows, using PostgreSQL 9.3 or later. Requires (and uses features of) C++17 compiler standard for latest version, and next major version C++20.

All above said, PQXX is its own way of operating--more transactional than connection oriented for example. If one were supporting multiple database types (say MySQL, etc.) in addition, one might use a different approach. But if one is all in on PostgreSQL, and writing C++, I highly recommend.